# Given an array of N elements. The task is to check if the elements in the array are first strictly increasing then strictly decreasing

Tags: python

- Example:
  Input: arr[] = [-3, 9, 11, 20, 17, 5, 1]
  Output: YES

Input: arr[] = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 11]
Output: NO

I tried with method but its throwing error as list index out of range.
And also do i need to increment 'i' in every iteration?

```
def checkType(arr,n):
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    #print(i)
    if (arr[i]<=arr[i+1]): #and (arr[n-1]<=arr[n-2]):
      print('YES')
    else:
      print('NO')
if __name__ == "__main__" :
  arr=[-3, 9, 11, 20, 17, 5, 1]
  n=len(arr)
  checkType(arr,n)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:-

```
arr = [-3, 9, 11, 20, 17, 5, 1]

if sorted(arr) == arr or sorted(arr, reverse=True) == arr:
  print('The array is ordered - either ascending or descending')
else:
  print('The array is not ordered')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
arr = [-3, 9, 11, 20, 17, 5, 1]
lst = [x - y for x, y in zip(arr, arr[1:])]
y = 1
value = 'YES'
for i in lst:
    if ((i < 0) != y) and (y == 1):
        y = 0
    elif ((i < 0) != y) and (y == 0):
        value = 'NO'
        break
print(value)
```

Output:

```
YES
```

Comment: Its quite to figure the code, can we optimize the code i have written?